# WPF TextBox Binding to SQL Table Column

Tags: wpf

This is for a WPF application with VS2010.

I have a SQL database in EquipmentTracker.mdf.
I have a table called EquipmentData.
This table contains a Column named Manufacturer.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:EquipmentTrackerDataSet x:Key="equipmentTrackerDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="equipmentDataViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=EquipmentData, Source={StaticResource equipmentTrackerDataSet}}" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource equipmentTrackerDataSet}, Path=EquipmentData/Manufacturer}" />
```

But when I run the application, the TextBox is still blank(empty).
What am I missing here?

Tried this way too...same result; blank TextBox:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource equipmentTrackerDataSet}}" Text="{Binding Path=EquipmentData/Manufacturer}" />
```

Comment: You should use a dot instead of slash to access object properties : EquipmentData.Manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

I would still be interested in knowing why it would not display the value when bound directly to the table, but when I created a VIEW and bound to it, it appears to work as I had expected.

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource equipmentDataViewSource}}" Text="{Binding Path=Manufacturer}" />
```